# react component does not reload after ajax request changes state

Tags: ajax, reactjs, state, axios

I apologize if this has been asked and answered, but I've search and cannot find the answer. This is my first time making Ajax requests so I'm sure I'm doing something a bit wrong and any help or best practice advise would be appreciated.

The problem is my react page loads with all the components empty. From the Docs :

> Calling setState() in this method (componentDidMount) will trigger an extra rendering

While in the example I'm showing, I'm calling a function that calls componentDidMount, I'd expect the same functionality. And, just in case I tested it by putting all of my logic into componentDidMount, and I get the exact same behavior. So, I'd expect to have a momentarily empty screen, or temporarily show hard coded state, but then re-render when state is received via ajax. However, it never re-renders. If I manually trigger a state change on the page by pushing a button to add or remove an item, I immediately see all of the data from my ajax request.

Everything works fine when state is hard coded.

From React Docs and here, I see that most people put ajax requests in componentDidMount, so this is where I start it. I'm trying to keep all my requests in a separate file if I can, but even when I remove the loadEntries function and the getEntries function, and put all the processing into componentDidMount, I get the same problem. If it is important, we are only talking about importing 20 or so objects similar to those shown hard coded into state.

I appreciate the help. Let me know if I've done something dumb!

```
// My higher Order Component
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Today from '../pages/Today';

export default class TodayContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.loadEntries = this.loadEntries.bind(this);

  this.state = {goalItems: [{entry_type: 1, date: "2017-12-20", id: 3, content: "other good stuff", completed: 1}],
                targetItems: [{entry_type: 2, date: "2017-12-20", id: 3, content: "Fix my hat", completed: 1}],
                successItems: [{entry_type: 3, date: "2017-12-20", id: 3, content: "Petted Cat"}],
                quoteItem: {entry_type: 4, date: "2017-12-20", id: 1, content: "This is a quote.", author: "me"}};
  }

componentDidMount() {
  this.loadEntries();
}

loadEntries() {
  let goalArray = [];
  let targetArray = [];
  let successArray = [];
  let quote = {};
  let scheduleArray = [];

Network.getEntries().then((entries) => {
  for (let entry of entries.data) {
    switch (entry.entry_type_id) {
      case 1:
          goalArray.push(entry);
          break;
      case 2:
          targetArray.push(entry);
          break;
      case 3:
          successArray.push(entry);
          break;
      case 4:
          quote = entry;
          break;
      case 5:
          scheduleArray.push(entry);
    }
  }
});

  let stateInit = {
    goalItems: goalArray,
    targetItems: targetArray,
    successItems: successArray,
    quoteItem: quote,
    scheduleItems: scheduleArray
  };

  this.setState(stateInit);
  }


//My Network File.
import axios from 'axios';

export function getEntries(){
  return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/entry');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **setState** call is being executed before the Promise of **Network.getEntries** is resolved. So you must call it inside the **then**

```
loadEntries() {
  let goalArray = [];
  let targetArray = [];
  let successArray = [];
  let quote = {};
  let scheduleArray = [];

Network.getEntries().then((entries) => {
  for (let entry of entries.data) {
    switch (entry.entry_type_id) {
      case 1:
          goalArray.push(entry);
          break;
      case 2:
          targetArray.push(entry);
          break;
      case 3:
          successArray.push(entry);
          break;
      case 4:
          quote = entry;
          break;
      case 5:
          scheduleArray.push(entry);
    }
  }

  let stateInit = {
    goalItems: goalArray,
    targetItems: targetArray,
    successItems: successArray,
    quoteItem: quote,
    scheduleItems: scheduleArray
  };

  this.setState(stateInit);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to move the let stateInit... this.setState code inside the then block of your request so it executes after the request completes.